# Can not find the tag library descriptor for "/birt.tld" After adding birt.tld in the WEB-INF/tld folder

Tags: birt

In birt.tld file the below lines showing error.

```
<tag-class>org.eclipse.birt.report.taglib.ViewerTag</tag-class>
<tag-class>org.eclipse.birt.report.taglib.ReportTag</tag-class>
<tag-class>org.eclipse.birt.report.taglib.ParamTag</tag-class>
<tag-class>org.eclipse.birt.report.taglib.ParamValueTag</tag-class>
<tag-class>org.eclipse.birt.report.taglib.RequesterTag</tag-class>
<tag-class>org.eclipse.birt.report.taglib.ParamDefTag</tag-class>
```

The error showing for above line is:

```
The tag handler class for(org.eclipse.birt.report.taglib.ParamDefTag) was not found on the Java Build Path.
```

Same for all the lines. I am not getting what to do. There is no any jar files found for them to include. 
In birt.jsp this is a jsp file I have created. The error in the line :

```
<%@ taglib uri="/birt.tld" prefix="birt" %>
```

Error is : 
    `Can not find the tag library descriptor for "/birt.tld"`

After adding birt.tld in the WEB-INF/tld folder, I am getting these errors.

Comment: And also am getting this error in the console,                                                                  Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/BirtWithJsp] threw exception [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/birt/report/taglib/component/ParameterField] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.birt.report.taglib.component.ParameterField

Answer (score 0):

```
  <jsp-config>
    <taglib>
       <taglib-uri>/birt.tld</taglib-uri>
       <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tlds/birt.tld</taglib-location>
   </taglib>
  </jsp-config>
```

put above configuration to `web.xml`, try some location